# Pass information to php file from javascript while restricting user from doing it their self?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am making a game where the battle system uses javascript to battle.  At the end of the battle you either win or lose.  If the user wins, I need to update the mysql database with the XP they earned.

The best way I can think of doing this is to have the javascript run an ajax function when the user wins that POSTs something like addxp.php?amount=235, but if I do that then the user can easilly look at the source and see that they can just enter in that page themself to update their xp without battling.  But this is the only way I know how to do it?

Help please :-/

Comment: the only secure way is to switch to server-side

Answer (score 1):

If you rely on the code running on the client's web browser to update the battle results, you do not have control over that code. Many javascript and flash games that have a high score board that depend on the browser sending in the high score registration are vulnerable to this. There is no real easy way around this.

You can try to obfuscate things somewhat, but someone who's interested enough is going to be able to fairly easily get around this.

As knoopx mentioned in his comments, the only sure-fire way to get around this is to do computations server-side. For example, the client browser sends user actions to the server, and the server is the one that determines the outcome of the battle, inserts the result into the mySQL db, and sends the result back to the client. This is obviously a major architectural change and you'll have to decide whether it's worth it.

Comment: Drat.  I wanted to make an awesome browser based RPG that actually lets your pick your moves and stuff instead of just click fight and it doing it for you...  I can't think of any other way to do it besides flash, but I'm not very good with flash :(

Answer (score 1):

This one is tricky and unfortunately there is no easy solution. I can give you some advice that helped me when I was creating a flash-game with a cash-prize. It worked quite well for me, but again - it was by no means full proof.

First of all do some thinking about the highest score it would be possible to achieve over a given time period. For example, you could say that the highest score you could reasonably get after playing for 1 minute is 200 points.

Each time someone starts playing the game, you do an AJAX call to your server to obtain a game ID. At set intervals (say 10 seconds), you make your game phone home with the game ID and the latest score. This way the only way to cheat would be to create a script that periodically contacts the server with a slowly incrementing score that falls under your maximum. Not a difficult thing to do, but at least now we're entering the territory where we've eliminated the casual louts with TamperData and a few minutes to kill boredom with.

Another thing you can do when you send back the current score is the current status of the gameboard. This isn't so useful for catching cheats live, but it's a very good tool you can use when awarding a prize to check that the high-score is a genuine one. This adds another layer of complexity to your system and hopefully make some of the more slightly-hard-core louts get bored and find something else to do.

My last suggestion is this - you in no way make your users immediately aware of what you're doing. That is to say, that if someone's score falls above your high-score/time threshold, you do nothing to let them know that they've tripped your cheat-detector. In the game I created, I even recorded their high-score along with their cookie. When getting the highscores from your database you SELECT * FROM scores WHERE cheated = FALSE OR cookie = userscookie. This way, unless they clear their cookie and check again, it will appear (only to them) that their hack attempt was successful.

Oh and one last thing; minify your javascript. This will obfuscate the code and make it very hard to read. Again, someone determined enough can easily circumvent this and look at your code, but it's all about making your system complex enough that people won't bother.

Unfortunately the web's strongest point can sometimes also be its weakest. It is the nature of the WWW that source code is open and available for anyone to read, which means that keeping secrets from your users is very hard if not impossible.

Comment: Also, you can flag a game as suspicious if it misses a phone home or takes too long to respond. Be careful with the "taking to long to respond" bit though.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Unfortunately I don't think it'll work with my game as theres not really a score involved, just winning or losing the current fight.  But that definitely makes me think that I can figure something out if I think waaay outside the box.

Comment: Is your RPG turn-based or real time?

Comment: Turn based, think Pokemon or early FF, or this specifically: http://seanmadi.com/ssland/battle/

Comment: And is the way to win the battle entirely logic-based or is there an element of luck (randomness).